# Combine two columns in SQL for WHERE clause (sqlite)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to select data from a table whereby the where clause combines two fields to locate the specific data to be fetched.
The code below does not work.

```
Select Email from users where FirstName || ' ' ||  LastName AS Nominative == 'fjpsojp 09809'
```

Comment: Any reason to not compare the first and last name separately like this `SELECT Email FROM users WHERE FirstName = 'fjpsojp' AND LastName = '09809'`? You could split the full name into parts in Python with something like this `full_name.split()`.

Comment: If your queries work when fed directly into SQL, you are probably having a problem with your double and single quotes with Python strings.

Comment: The query works without the AS part, not with it.

Comment: I should add, in the 'DB Browser for SQLite'.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Is there any error message?

Comment: If you must use AS, try this: Select Email , FirstName || ' ' ||  LastName AS Nominative from users where Nominative  == 'fjpsojp 09809'

Answer (score 3):

If the fields Email, FirstName and LastName are in the Users table, then you can do your select like this:

```
select Email, FirstName || ' ' || LastName as Nominative 
from users 
where FirstName = 'fjpsojp'
and LastName = '09809';
```

This will give you results with two columns: one for **Email**, another for **Nominative**